# CRM D365 update polymorphic/multitable lookup via Plugin

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I'm trying to update a polymorphic lookup column on a table via plugin code and it doesn't seem happening. Wondering what additional I’m missing.

```
var entity1Id = "af435c64-a264-4f2a-9cee-22069ce36b3c";
var destinationEntity = new Entity("bookableresourcebooking", new Guid(myBookingGuid));
destinationEntity["my_ploymorphiclookupid"] = new EntityReference("my_entity1", new Guid(entity1Id));
organizationService.Update(destinationEntity);
```

`my_ploymorphiclookupid` is a polymorphic lookup (N:1) to my_entity1

Answer (score 0):

Code looks fine. If you didn’t see any runtime errors in plug-in trace log, then few diagnosis steps needed.

1. Check audit history of that record
2. Chances of any other plugin steps replacing the value back or rolling back
3. Try to profile/debug the plugin for clues